# Slonik dynamic insert query via sql tag

Tags: javascript, sql, node.js, node-postgres, slonik

Via [Slonik](https://github.com/gajus/slonik) I try to create a sql statement in a dynamic way. I have a list of keys I want to use for my insert statement and to create a list of values.

This is an example of my setup. Though the definition of my insert columns always fails.

```
  const keys = [
    'type',
    'substance_group',
    'substance',
    'unit',
    'zone_id',
    'zone',
    'sector',
    'sub_sector',
    'sum_bruto',
    'sum_netto',
  ];
  const emissionValues = values<string>(pick(emission, keys));

  //  (type, substance_group, substance, unit, zone_id, zone, sector, sub_sector, sum_bruto, sum_netto)
  const query = sql`
    INSERT INTO api.emissions
    (${sql.array(keys, 'text')})
     VALUES (${emissionValues.join(',')})
  `;
```

I tried these forms:

- `${sql.array(keys, 'text')}`
- `${sql.join(keys, sql`, `)}`
- or plain `${keys.join(',')`

But none are allowed by the sql query builder tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is covered in the [documentation](https://github.com/gajus/slonik), but you need to use `sql.identifier` for identifiers, e.g.

```
const identifiers = keys.map((key) => {
  return sql.identifier([key]);
});

sql`
  INSERT INTO api.emissions
  (${sql.join(identifiers, sql`, `)})
  VALUES
  (${sql.join(values, sql`, `)})
`
```

If you are inserting multiple rows, then have a look at [`sql.unnest`](https://github.com/gajus/slonik#sqlunnest).